# How do I colour two sides of a triangle?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG triangle and I want to change the colour of 1, 2 or all sides depending on a tri-state value.

The code I have so far is below:

```
<div class="triangle-container">
  <svg height="500" width="500">
    <polygon points="250,60 100,400 400,400" class="triangle" />

    <path d="M250,60 100,400 400,400z" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-linejoin="miter" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

I have tried using a number of `polygon` but the lines here don't join very nicely. Ideally I want this to work using just one `polygon` or `path` but I am unsure how I can set the colour of 1 or 2 of the lines.

codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvEWvX

Thanks

Comment: you could probably do something with stroke-dasharray if you calculated the values carefully so that the dash corresponded to either 1 or 2 sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 3 different lines grouped in a `<g>` element with the `class ="triangle`

```css
body {
  background: #AA3A3B;
}

.triangle-container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.triangle-container:hover .triangle, .triangle-container:active .triangle {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
          transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.triangle-container .triangle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-width: 8;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 250px 250px;
          transform-origin: 250px 250px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
   
    <g class="triangle">
    <path d="M250,60L100,400" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M100,400L400,400" stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M400,400L250,60" stroke="gold" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" />
    </g>
     
  </svg>
</div>
```

This is another example where I'm using only one path but I'm reusing this path 3 times every time with a different `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`

```css
body {
  background: #AA3A3B;
}

.triangle-container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.triangle-container:hover .triangle, .triangle-container:active .triangle {
  stroke: blue;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.triangle-container .triangle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 8;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 250px 250px;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-container">
  <svg height="500" width="500">
    <defs>
      <path id="t" d="M250,60 100,400 400,400z" />
    </defs>

<g class="triangle">
    <use xlink:href="#t" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray = "371.62 671.62" />
    <use xlink:href="#t"  stroke="gold" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray = "300 743.24" stroke-dashoffset = "-371.62" />
    <use xlink:href="#t"  stroke="skyblue" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray = "371.62 671.62" stroke-dashoffset = "-671.62" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

#### UPDATE

Maybe you want something like this. In this case I'm using only one path each time. I've calculated the stroke-dasharray so that only 1 2 or 3 sides are stroked:

```css
svg{width:130px; border:1px dotted }

body {
  background: #AA3A3B;
}

.triangle-container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.triangle-container:hover .triangle, .triangle-container:active .triangle {
  /*stroke: blue;*/
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.triangle-container .triangle {
  fill: transparent;
  /*stroke: blue;*/
  stroke-width: 8;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 250px 250px;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <defs>
      <path id="t" d="M250,60 100,400 400,400z" />
    </defs>
<use class="triangle" xlink:href="#t" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray = "371.62 671.62" />
  </svg>

   <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <use class="triangle"  xlink:href="#t"  stroke="gold" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray = "671.62 371.62 " stroke-dashoffset = "0" /></svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
      <use class="triangle"  xlink:href="#t"  stroke="skyblue" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round"  />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.